# Read a Json file extract the data and generate a CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm not sure but it some think to do with the loop on reading the file
if some can have a look at my code and point me the error that would be great

The error I got is `KeyError: 'MBWritten'`.

My code is:

```
for file_name in file_name_list:
    with open(file_name) as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)
        symmetrixID= data['symmetrixID']
        pgname= data['pgname']
        for row in data['perf_data']:
            MBWritten = row['MBWritten']
            timestamp = row['timestamp']
            Writes = row['Writes']
            AvgIOSize = row['AvgIOSize']
            Reads = row['Reads']
            MBRead = row['MBRead']
            PercentBusy = row['PercentBusy']
            IOs = row['IOs']
            MBs = row['MBs']
        for timestamp in [timestamp]:
            EXEC_TIME = epoch2human(timestamp)
            joined = ",".join([str(c) for c in [symmetrixID, pgname, MBWritten, MBRead,
                                                Reads, Writes, MBs, AvgIOSize,
                                                PercentBusy, IOs, EXEC_TIME]])
            print(joined)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you 'MBWritten' doesn't exist in the current row.

You could use the `dict.get()` method to avoid this error. For example:

```
row.get('MBWritten')
```

This will return `None` if the key can't be found. If you want to set a default value if the key can't be found you just add it as the second argument. For example:

```
row.get('MBWritten', 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

That error means that the row does not have a field named 'MBWritten'

We won't be able to help debug this without understanding the actual data from your data_file.

The point of the error though is you are loading the data from that file_name as json and then iterating through every field of the 'perf_data' key. Somewhere in that data there is no 'MBWritten' field and you are getting a key error.

You would get this error if your data looked something like this like this and a field was missing MBWritten

```
{
  'perf_data': [
                 {'MBWritten': 7, 'timestamp': 1234, ...},
                 {'timestamp': 8837, ...}
               ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Nick this is how my data look:

Comment: {
  "symmetrixID": "000123401234", 
  "pgname": "fa1d10_8d10_pg", 
  "perf_data": {
    "to": 3, 
    "from": 1, 
    "result": [
      {
        "MBWritten": 0.0, 
        "timestamp": 1553787300000, 
        "Writes": 0.0, 
        "MBRead": 0.0, 
        "IOs": 0.0, 
        "Reads": 0.0, 
        "PercentBusy": 0.0, 
        "AvgIOSize": 0.0, 
        "MBs": 0.0
      },

Comment: Hey Max, so it looks like MBWritten is nested one more level deep. MBWritten is within result.
It goes data --> perf_data --> result --> MBWritten

Do you see this?

Comment: yes it's a nested report  Nick my Problem is i'am a complete new to python started it   very recently. the way how to get a nested data is complete unknown to me, thanks for pointing it's a nested data

Comment: You just need another for loop. within for row in data['perf_data'] you need a loop like for obj in row['result']

Comment: by adding the second loop i have this : ValueError: Extra data: line 45 column 1 - line 7921 column 1 (char 922 - 171751)